# apache flink checkpoint is finished but doesn't completed

Tags: streaming, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a tough problem about apache `flink`.
The checkpoint is  finished, but the checkpoint is stuck at 'IN_PROGRESS' state. And there is no useful information found in log files.
could anyone give me some advice about this.

**flink version: 1.9.3_2.12**

[checkpoint state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7grp.png)

[jobmanager log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObUWG.png)

[checkpoint file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roZ18.png)

Comment: Which sink are you using?

Comment: This may be because JobManager is stucked in materializing metadata, which may be caused by the problem between JM and HDFS. You can use jstack to locate the stuck problem.